# Run the android app developed in Android studio on Lenovo A6000

Tags: android

I have made an android app in Android studio 1.4 and now I want to run it in Lenovo A6000 phone. I have enabled the USB debugging option in the developers options and also added the following code in the build.gradle file:

```
 android {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                debuggable true
            }
        }

    }
```

I have added this command also in android.manifest.xml file.

```
android:debuggable="true" in <application> tag.

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true"
        >
```

But still when I connect the USB to the phone then it doesn't show my phone on clicking on the Run button in the Android Studio.

Comment: When we first time connect our device to usb cable a pop up apears on device. you make sure that you have clicked allow debugging for this device to make it debuggable.

Comment: yeah I have enabled that config. Then also its not showing my mobile on my android studio

Comment: Latest version of Android Studio, is 2.2. Just saying

Comment: Android Studio current version is 2.2. Why 4.0?

Comment: yup it is changed.

Comment: Install Lenovo A6000 adb driver in your computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have enable the developer option.

Sometime its the glitch that the device is not detected.

Some things that i have done have worked.

1) Restart your device and Android studio.

2) Go to developer option > Revoke USB debugging authorization 
Then connect the the device to your laptop/pc, on the device it ask for the permission dailog  like

[image: Allow usb debugging dailog]

Check always allow from this computer and you are done :)

Answer (score 1):

Install Lenovo A6000 [Driver](https://androidurdu.net/download-lenovo-a6000-plus-usbadb-drivers-official/),

Install [ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/),

Open Command Prompt, and go to `YourSDK/platform-tools/` , and type

```
adb devices  (for Window ), ( Type ./adb devices ) for OSX, which will show connected devices list.
```

If you cannot see your device, type

```
adb kill-server, ( ./adb kill-server for OSX )

adb start-server, ( ./adb start-server for OSX ),
```

and then , you can try `adb restart`, to restart ADB.

You can use these commands, if you cannot see `Logcat` in Android Monitor.

Hope, it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution!

1. Download and install [PdaNet+](http://pdanet.co/a/) to fix connection issues between my
   computer and android device
2. Enable USB debugging on my android device
3. Run my app and Bingo! My android device is now recognized by Android Studio

Happy Coding!

Comment: I have to install PdaNet+ on my mobile or computer?

Comment: in your computer.

Comment: i have installed it in my phone and my laptop as well. Then connected the both through bluetooth, but still my phone is not detected in my android studio.

Comment: @shikher.mishra have you connected successfully or not?

Comment: No not from this method I am not able to. But from above answer I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have the device drivers installed in your system for your device.
2. Allow USB debugging in your device.

   First, Developers Options should be enabled in your device, then

   Settings > Developers Options > USB Debugging(enable)

3.Connect your device as a Camera

Comment: so, will it show my device when I click on the RUN button in android studio?

Comment: Generally it does. Sometimes I also face this issue when I connect any new device to my system.